# jQuery Datatables automatic scroll for details-control

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables and I want to know how to automatically scroll to show the details-control when it is pressed. If I click the last row of my table it will open the information but the user will never know to scroll down. Is it possible to have it automatically scroll to show the details when using details-control?

When the green plus sign is chosen it appears as so:
[image]

After you manually scroll it then appears:
[image]

Is it possible to have it automatically scroll for the user to see easier than having to manually scroll?

```
var someTable = $('#processing1').DataTable( {
        "columns": [ 
            {
                "class":          "details-control1",
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ""
            },
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "dealerID" },
            { "data": "Date_Received" },
            { "data": "op_id" },
            { "data": "Date_Due" },
            { 
              "data": "Date_Complete",
              "render": function(data){
              return ((data) ? "COMPLETED" : "PROCESSING");
              }
            },
            { "data": "Completed_Late" },
            { "data": "Closed_by" },
            { "data": "Rmks" },
            { "data": "Processing_Location" },
            { "data": "Item_Count" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "targets": [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], "searchable": false }
        ],
        "sDom": '<"row view-filter"<"col-sm-12"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"f><"clearfix">>>t<"row view-pager"<"col-sm-12"<"text-center"ip>>>',
        select: {
            style: 'single'
        },
        scrollY:        250,
        deferRender:    true,
        scroller:       true,
        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ <label for='processing1_length'><strong>records per page</strong></label>",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "«",
                "sNext": "»",
            }
        }
    });

    // Array to track the ids of the details displayed rows
    var somedetailRows = [];

    $('#processing1 tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td.details-control1', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = someTable.row( tr );
        var idx = $.inArray( tr.attr('id'), somedetailRows );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            tr.removeClass( 'details1' );
            row.child.hide();

            // Remove from the 'open' array
            somedetailRows.splice( idx, 1 );
        }
        else {
            tr.addClass( 'details1' );
            row.child( format( row.data() ) ).show();

            // Add to the 'open' array
            if ( idx === -1 ) {
                somedetailRows.push( tr.attr('id') );
            }
        }
    });

    // On each draw, loop over the `somedetailRows` array and show any child rows
    someTable.on( 'draw', function () {
        $.each( somedetailRows, function ( i, id ) {
            $('#'+id+' td.details-control1').trigger( 'click' );
        });
    });
```

I have added this plugin: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

but cannot figure out where to insert this code and what to replace `object` with.

```
var scroller = oTable.fnSettings().nTable.parentNode;                                               
$(scroller).scrollTo( object, 1 );
```

What does object need to be changed to?

**EDIT**

```
$('#processing1 tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td.details-control1', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = someTable.row( tr );
        var i = $(this).index() ;
        var idx = $.inArray( tr.attr('id'), somedetailRows );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            tr.removeClass( 'details1' );
            row.child.hide();

            // Remove from the 'open' array
            somedetailRows.splice( idx, 1 );
        }
        else {
            tr.addClass( 'details1' );
            row.child( format( row.data() ) ).show();

            // Add to the 'open' array
            if ( idx === -1 ) {
                somedetailRows.push( tr.attr('id') );
                someTable.scroller().scrollToRow(i + 2);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2140/scroll-to-highlighted-row

Comment: Yes, you need to add `scrollTo` jQuery library. https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Comment: The `object` value can be replaced with anything you want to target (or scrollTo). Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo#target) for the plugin to see all the options you have. You can target offsets, DOM elements, jQuery objects, etc.

Comment: @Vicki, use jQuery to get the index of the <tr> you clicked on, then you can use that to target your scroll. This will give you the effect of scrolling to the clicked on <tr>. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) extension. In the click event that expands the child records, get the index of the clicked row. You need to scroll to a row which is index + n, where n is the number of rows which would allow the child records to be visible.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    scroller:       true,
    scrollY:        400,
    scrollCollapse: false
});
```

This js fired whenever a row is clicked and makes the scroll happen - in your version it would be in the `$('#processing1 tbody').on` event

```
    $('tr').click(function(e){
        var i = $(this).index() ;
        table.scroller().scrollToRow(i + 2);
    });
```

Here is a jsfiddle which shows what I mean:  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/r7cgysf6/2/)

If you click on a row, the code gets the clicked index, adds 2 and then scrolls to the resulting index.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** [markpsmith's answer on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33505979/3960969) is correct and should get credit for it, my thoughts are merely an extension of his.

To solve your problem, you can:

#### 1. Add the [scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) plugin by linking to the these files in your document:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.3.0/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.3.0/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css" />
```

#### 2. Add the following option to your DataTable:

```
scroller: true
```

#### 3. Add the following logic to the click handler of your `td` or `tr`

```
var i = $(this).index();
table.scroller().scrollToRow(i);
```

#### [Click here to see a working demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/nnb97rh9/5/)

**NOTE:** The DataTable plugin can be awkward when scrolling to table rows if more than one table row is open at a time. You can see what I mean by first clicking on a few rows without closing any of the open rows. Then, close all rows, then open only one row at a time (close all rows before opening another row). This is likely the behavior that you want, so you will need to write a few lines of code to ensure that only one row is open at a time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In the above example, the ajax data is not coming now. Added static data from https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array. The new working link is - https://jsfiddle.net/ravindragullapalli/c6xm0rsb/